# how do i add or delete something from an array?

Tags: java, arrays

I am writing this program that will take in the names, ages and salaries for 5 different people from the user and will put them in an array.

I then want to write a method that will ask the user for another name, age and salary and add that into the array. Also a method that will as for the name of someone who's already in the array and will delete the information of the person with that age from the array.

The first method will increase the array size by 1 and the second will decrease the array size by 1. so far this is what I have:

```
ArrayList<details> details = new ArrayList<details>();

for(int x = 0; x < 4; x++) {

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter the first name: ");
        String firstName = scan.nextLine();

        System.out.println("Enter the last name: ");
        String lastName = scan.nextLine();

        System.out.println("Enter the age: ");
        int age = scan.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Enter the salary: ");
        double salary = scan.nextDouble();

details.add (new details(firstName, lastName, age, salary));

}
```

I don't know how to go about doing this. I need some help!
thanks!

Comment: The List interface has two remove methods.  One by object and one by index value.  I suggest using the remove by index, and use a reverse for loop to find the details object to remove.  Also, class names start with a capital letter in Java.  Your class should be Details.

Comment: You keep calling it "array", and in the code I see a ArrayList. Pretty different problem.

Comment: http://download.java.net/jdk8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#remove-int-

Comment: If you want to delete by name only, I think a map is a better suit. E.g. create a map from name to details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have a class Person with the class variables you require (name,age,salary)

```
class Person {
    private int age;
    private dobule salary;
    private String firstname;
    private String lastname;
}
```

Define the getter and setter methods for each of the class variables. For e.g

```
public void setAge(int age){
    this.age = age;
}
public int getAge(){
    return this.age;
}
```

In your main class read the input from STDIN as you are doing it. Instantiate the Person object for each of the 5 person.

```
Person employee = new Person();
employee.setAge(x);
employee.setFirstName(x);
employee.setLastName(y);
employee.setSalary(y);
```

Now, you can [add](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#add%28E%29) each Person to your list and [remove](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#remove%28int%29) them too.

For removing any Person you would have to search for the Person through the ArrayList by name. That would be iterating over the length of ArrayList and comparing the name of each.

The final class would look like,

```
public class Solution{

   private ArrayList<Person> details = new ArrayList()<Person>; 

   public static void main(){
       // Here you loop for reading from STDIN as you are already doing.
       // addPerson() would be used to add to ArrayList and removePerson() for the other
   }
   public addPerson(String firstName, String lastName, int age, int salary){
        //Create the Person object
       details.add(<person object>);
   }
   public removePerson(name){
       details.remove(index);
       // to get index it would require iterating over the ArrayList. 
       // It would be better if you use a Map instead (as other suggest) 
       // with name as the key 
   }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I already have a people's class that has all the getters and setter but to add a new person's information to the array, do I have to add anything new to my people's class? do i need to add an update method? if so how do I do this? how will this method look?

Comment: I have edited my answer for the two methods which you mentioned. I have skipped the iterator loop. Hope you will figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

dud first of all, i can see that u have used arrayList name & Class name both same so please update that.

secondary use Map in place of Class like in if condition

```
  if(){
  Map userDetails = new HashMap();
 map.put("firstname",firstname);
 ..
 ..
 map.put("salary",scan.nextDouble());
 details.add(map)
 }
```

and on time of delete iterate ArrayList

```
 for(int i=0;i<details.size();i++){
    Map tempMap = details.get(i);
    if(temp.get("firstname").toString() == "Given Name"){
    }else{
       // your logic
    }
 }
```

Hope will help you please let me know if any doubts.

Answer (score 0):

use this code for removing employee

```
void removeEmployee(String name){
    for(Employee emp :details){
        if(name.equals(emp.getName())){
            details.remove(emp);
            break;
        }

    }
}
```

and do include exception handling